# Is it possible to bundle Node addons for browsers?

Tags: c++, node.js, browser, browserify, node.js-addon

I have a very simple C++ node addon. It exports 2 methods using the `NODE_SET_METHOD` node function. Both of them simply return a string and/or print something to the console.

```cpp
void Method1(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(
        isolate, "world"));
}

void Method2(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    printf("Testing testing.\n");
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello there"));
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method1);
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "welcome", Method2);
}
```

The build is working just fine. Calling those functions from JavaScript through Node also returns and prints out the expected values. What I am struggling with is to bundle this entire thing (using browserify) so that I can call the same functions from the browser. Browserify refuses to build. I keep getting this error message:

```
> npx browserify index.js
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module './build/Release/hello' from 'F:\workspace\c\addon\hello\index.js'
    required by F:\workspace\c\addon\hello\index.js
    at F:\workspace\c\addon\hello\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:136:35
    at load (F:\workspace\c\addon\hello\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:155:43)
    at onex (F:\workspace\c\addon\hello\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:180:17)
    at F:\workspace\c\addon\hello\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:15:69
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
```

I am starting to think that it is not possible to bundle node addons for front end use. Is there a way, however, to get around this problem and be able to include node addons for browser builds? Maybe a special way to write my `index.js` or something? Or is there a different way to create addons which circumvents this problem?

Comment: emscripten is probably your best bet here

Comment: to directly answer your question, no. webassembly is probably the best answer, and as daniel jour notes above, emscripten is a good way to get there.

Comment: Thank you. I was mostly looking for that confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The following repository has a good set of node native add-on examples

[node-addon-examples](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples)

**Node add-on cannot bundle with browsers**; the return value scenario is explained in

[hello_world example](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/blob/master/1_hello_world/napi/hello.cc)

Comment: I am probably going to go with wasm then. However, it would be helpful to know why it is not possible. The link you shared for return value scenario doesn't really contain any explanation. Do you happen to know any source which documents why it is not possible?